# Crossfilter reductio post cap

Tags: crossfilter, reductio

I am having trouble trying to use reductio's post().cap functionality. My dataset is like so.

```
[{foo: 'one', bar: 'B', hits:10},
{foo: 'one', bar: 'B', hits:20},
{foo: 'two', bar: 'B', hits:50},
{foo: 'two', bar: 'B', hits:100},
{foo: 'one', bar: 'A', hits:150}.........]
```

What I am looking for is

```
[key: 'B', value:{count=4, sum=180}, 
key: 'A', value:{count=1, sum=150},
key: 'others', value:{count=7, sum=60}]
```

I have a foo dim setup as

```
var barDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.bar; });
var barGroup = reductio().count(true).sum('hits')(barDim.group());
```

Thanks in advance!

[reductio cap functionality](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#grouppostcaplength)

Comment: What does `console.log(fooGroup.post().cap(3)()` show you?

Comment: Also, for this group key, I'd think you'd want to define a dimension on `bar` rather than `foo`, but I assume that's just a mistake based on sample data :-)

Comment: It's not showing me in the correct order. It's capped based on natural order. I would like to post cap the result by decreasing sum values. Yes the key should be 'bar'. That's a mistake. :)

Comment: [key: 'A', value:{count=4, sum=150}, 
key: 'B', value:{count=1, sum=180},
key: 'others', value:{count=7, sum=60}]

Comment: You'll need to define an ordering on the group using Crossfilter's `group.order` method. Reductio just uses the same ordering as `group.top`. Something like `bargroup.order(function(p) { return p.sum; })` should work. https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order

Comment: @EthanJewett I have specified a group order. When I do `console.log(bargroup.top(Infinity))` it shows me in the order of sum. When I do `console.log(bargroup.post().cap(3)())` it shows me natural order. I'm stumped. :(

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please open an issue on GitHub and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately during the comment thread above I was not familiar enough with the Reductio `post` API as I don't use it myself. It doesn't currently respect group ordering, but it does provide its own API to control order. For example:

```
group.post().sortBy('value.sum', d3.descending).cap(3)()
```

Note that the ordering function here is `d3.descending`, which is available if you are using D3.js. Otherwise you can use any ordering function with a similar API.

I also note that the `sortBy` API isn't documented. I will try to get this done so that others can discover it.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. This works. I intended to use the post cap because of the 'others' aggregation. Till now I was using fake group in crossfilter which didn't provide ;others'. Probably it would but it would require a bit of coding. Anyway after all this I would want to pass this to dc.js chart. However I get a.group.all is not a function. So I've gone ahead and created a fake group.

Comment: Yup, you can create a fake group based on the result of `group.post().sortBy....cap(3)` and it should work. :-) Cheers.